# Getting different files when installing making a new Jekyll project

Tags: cmd, jekyll

I've just recently started a course on Jekyll and I've followed every instruction the guy did, but when he gets to creating a new project through a terminal I follow everything he does and yet I get different files in my project folder than he does.

[image: These are the files he gets.]
These are the files he gets.

[image: And these are the files I get.]
And these are the files I get.

Why am I not getting the same files as he?
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Since jekyll 3.2, every layout, include and assets are hidden somewhere on you file system, thank to the new [gem based themes](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/themes/).

You can find them with : `bundle show minima` if you're using the default theme.

Good luck with this.